# Comment out graphviz code from getting compiled?

Tags: graphviz

How do you comment out code in graphviz so that I can label chunks of code without it getting compiled (If possible)?

I tried C++ style // but it did not work.

Comment: The Graphviz programs recognize both C-style `a->b /* my comment */ `and C++-style  `b->c // my other comment`.  Please provide an example of a non-working comment.

Comment: If you are using Graphviz via Python or some other language, you have to use their commenting rules.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: omg i realized i was using the wrong slash thx